# unique string from array of strings

Tags: php, arrays, string, unique

I want to create a string that is unique from all the strings in an array. I know that `unique_array` would create an array with unique values, but I want to create a new string that is unique from all the strings in the unique array. I want this in PHP.

For example, if I have `"1"`, `"2"` strings in the unique array. I would like to create a `"3"` string or `"a"` string or any other string with a different name then `"1"`, and `"2"`. Serialize a new string and add it into the array and check for `unique_array` sounds like it should work, but is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Tell us about the application of this?

Comment: This is for phpList, I think I will just append a uniqid() to the string.

Comment: Also google or search here for different methods for generating unique id's. At the moment it's difficult to give you a specific solution that suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sort($array);
$array[] = end($array) + 1;
```